# how to fix or work around different firebase service not available or not working?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have my application developed using Flutter and integrated different firebase services like auth, messaging etc..

This app is working fine on development and testing on device with debug and release builds but when I released new build on google play store(closed testing - alpha channel) then immediately got few crash report on sentry.

> By the way, I have uploaded many builds but not getting these kind of crashes
> before with the same app and firebase services but recently I have upgraded to
> Flutter 2 and latest firebase dependencies

> Crash Logs Info

```
    FirebaseException: [firebase_messaging/unknown] SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
      File "method_channel_messaging.dart", line 226, in MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken
```

```
FirebaseAuthException: [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.j: An internal error has occurred. [ unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.googleapis.com:443, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=216.58.195.138 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0) ]
  File "method_channel_user.dart", line 135, in MethodChannelUser.reload
  File "user.dart", line 260, in User.reload
  File "xx.dart", line 41, in xx.xx
...
(2 additional frame(s) were not displayed)
```

```
FirebaseAuthException: [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.j: An internal error has occurred. [ unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.googleapis.com:443, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=216.58.195.138 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0) ]
  File "method_channel_firebase_auth.dart", line 457, in MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInAnonymously
  File "firebase_auth.dart", line 393, in FirebaseAuth.signInAnonymously
  File "xx.dart", line 71, in xxx.xx
  File "xxx.dart", line 11, in xxx.xx
...
(2 additional frame(s) were not displayed)
```

> Device Info

```
device = Pixel 3  
device.family = Pixel 
environment = PRODUCTION 
event.environment = dart 
event.origin = flutter  
isSideLoaded = true 
level = error  
os = Android 9 
os.name = Android  
os.rooted = no 
dist = xxxxx 
release = x.x.x@x.x.x+xxxx 
user = x.x.x.x
```

```
device = Nexus 5X 
device.family = Nexus 
environment = PRODUCTION 
event.environment = dart 
event.origin = flutter 
installerStore = com.android.vending 
isSideLoaded = false 
level = error 
os = Android 6.0.1 
os.name = Android 
os.rooted = yes 
dist = xxxxxxx 
release = xx.xx.xx@x.x.x+xxxxxx
user = id:xxx
```

I have tried to look around and options why this can be happened or how can I fix or any possible work around.. but no luck till now.

Anyone is facing similar things? any help how can I add any work around for these?

I suspect, there might be something robot based testing for pre-launch report and that might cause these crashes.

Any thoughts or possible workarounds?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, face same issue